# What does each mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
myObj.FirstName = 'Phillip',
myObj.LastName = 'Senn';
for (var X in myObj) // FirstName LastName
for each (var X in myObj) // Phillip Senn
```

Q: Mentally, how do you read these two statements?

Comment: IE8 does not support 'for each'. How about IE9?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one ([`for ( in )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)) is reading property names from the object.

So you may read it as *for each property in `myObj`, assign it to `x`*.

The second one ([`for each ( in )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in)) is reading values of the properties in the object.

This one may be read as *for each property's value in `myObj`, assign it to `x`*.

Note that `for each` has limited browser support.

Also note that if extra properties are appearing in `for ( in )`, it is because it will look up the prototype chain for extra enumerable properties (and someone may have augmented `Object`, for example).

You can mitigate this with...

```
for (var x in myObj) {
   if ( ! myObj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
       continue;
   }
   // Now you are sure the property is of `myObj`
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/7ZVxX/).

Answer (score 1):

`for (var a in b)` is a way for getting the indices `a` of the given array `b`. When I'm muttering to myself as I read through code, I usually say something like "for every `X` in `myObj`".

If you use the `each` keyword, you will retrieve the values of the object (or array) in `myObj`. If you omit it, `myObj` will contain the keys (or array indices).

Comment: `for ( in )` should be avoided with `Array`s.

Comment: It's useful for associative arrays.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't actually have associative arrays, just `Object`s of which their properties can be set.

Comment: Right, and in those cases, `for (var a in b)` is useful. Would you care to explain why you think they should be avoided?

Comment: They are perfect for enumerating over an `Object`. Just not an `Array`. Doing so on an `Array` with enumerate extra properties besides numerical ones and may dredge up further stuff up the prototype chain.

Answer (score 1):

`for(var X in myObj)`

*For every member (key) in myObj*

`for each(var X in myObj)`

*For each member in myObj, get its value*

Answer (score 1):

`for` iterates through the **Names** of the properties of the object whereas `for each` iterates through the values of the properties.

See [for each](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/For_each...in) on MDN